# hosted landing page to download my app by platform/other

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store, branch.io

I have an android and iOS applications,
but I don't have a server that supports them. They are completely autonomous.

I am looking for a service provider that allows to host (Free?) a page where I will have 2 buttons, one to the iOS app download and one to the android google play store

I am currently using Branch.io to try to open the installed app / go to the correct store by the platform running the link.
However, in case the link is opened via a PC, I want the user to be redirected to this fallback url...

Is there any google/other free small site hosting service you know of?

Comment: You can create a very simple site which would work but I am happy to create one for you since it will only be one page. Also there are many free hosting sites like hostiner , 00webhost , x10hosting and many more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution provided by WebGuy is perfect. There is also an alternative with Branch.

If you do not have a website, Branch offers a customizable Branch hosted page called Deepviews.
With Deepviews you can provide your users with an opportunity to enter their mobile number so that they can text themselves Branch links to download your App.

If you wish to enable a Deepview for Desktop users for a single Branch link, you can add the parameter `$desktop_deepview` to your links. The value of the parameter should be set to the Deepview key you can to redirect the user to.

If you wish to enable a Desktop Deepview for all Branch links, you can do so in your Branch Dashboard at Web to `App> Deepview Previews> Desktop` and enable the Deepview of your choice.

(PS: The only drawback is you will not be able to add any Javascript logic to your Deepviews.)